# bootstrap modal hide

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

How do I hide the modal window without submitting the form?

In the modal-footer, I have two buttons,

```
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
```

When I click save, the form will be submitted. How do I prevent it from being submitted?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide more HTML? What do you want the form to do, besides hide the modal?

Comment: I'm using a link to hide the modal. Thanks.

Comment: I can give you better help if you provide more HTML--like the div that contains your modal and the links or buttons that invoke it.